# Replace "<=" with a drop down list value

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my script using the `if` function:

```
 If snSheets.Cells(snRow, snCol).Value <= sumSheets.Cells(sumRow, 2).Value
```

Here I will creat a drop down list in a cell include all the conditions include : "<" , ">" , "=" , "<=" , ">=" ;

How can I replace "<=" in my script with my drop down list value?

Comment: what kind of drop down list? inserted from the forms controls or from the active-x controls?

Answer (score 0):

```
If Application.Evaluate(snSheets.Cells(snRow, snCol).Value _
                   & opValue &  sumSheets.Cells(sumRow, 2).Value) Then
...
End If
```

Where opValue is `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`

Comment: Thank u ,I just realized the function by "if else",thanks all the same.